# Touchpad not workingon ASUS UX305 under Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: touchpad

I am new to Ubuntu (Linux)... 
I just got a new ASUS UX305 ultrabook with Intel core M 3 processor, 8 gb of RAM, 256 SSD, running Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu 15.10 (dual boot) with GRUB.
The  touchpad is not recognized and it is not working at all, i have to use a mouse...
As I mentioned, I am new to Linux, and I am not a computer professional (Medical Professional with interest in Linux), so xinput, terminal.....etc does not mean much to me, I really do not understand it.
If you still feel that you can help , please do I would really appreciate it. If not, that is ok too, I will look for an answer elsewhere.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thank you all!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp; uname -r; dkms status` terminal command.

Comment: I rejected a proposed edit from @CargoElf. If that is the original poster, please log in with your original account to edit.

Comment: Same issue. I've published a bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1514066