# Touchpad not working properly on ASUS UX330U

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, asus, elantech

I have an ASUS UX330U and I am running **Ubuntu 16.04.4** on it with **xfce** as window manager. *Sometimes* it happens that after **suspend** the touchpad is not working. The touchpad is working in the login-screen, but after successfull login, no touchpad. Note that this happens only *sometimes*.

I have tried `modprobe -r psmouse` and `modprobe psmouse` without any success.

This is the output of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1200:00 04F3:3022 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The kernel I am using is, according to the output of `uname -r`:

```
4.13.0-45-generic
```

According to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693701/touchpad-not-workingon-asus-ux305-under-ubuntu-15-10), the output of `dmesg | grep pnp` might be helpful:

```
[    0.220840] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.221221] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.221404] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.224220] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
[    0.956259] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
```

My questions are:

1. Why does the touchpad stops working *sometimes* after returning from suspend ?
2. Why is the touchpad still working in the login screen (in the cases where it is not working after logging in)?

And, of course, I would be happy if someone would tell me how to fix this.

---

**Update 1**

The output of `apt policy linux-generic-hwe-16.04` is as follows:

```
linux-generic-hwe-16.04:
  Installed: 4.13.0.45.64
  Candidate: 4.13.0.45.64
  Version table:
 *** 4.13.0.45.64 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

**Update 2**

Since updating to kernel 4.15, I have not experienced the error so far, seems like this has indeed solved the problem (as suggested in the comments).

Comment: Maybe it will work better with the 4.15 kernel. If you simply `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` it will be installed. Today they uploaded the new major version for 16.04. If you are using a mirror, the repo will be synced later.

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't get the new kernel version (yet...?), I'll probably have to wait, I guess

Comment: What does `apt policy linux-generic-hwe-1604` show?

Comment: @Pilot6 updated the question

Comment: Some people already have the 4.15. It probably didn't reach the German mirror yet. You can switch to the main server to get it.

Comment: @Pilot6 thanks for the suggestions, I'll wait until tomorrow (some work needs to be done now) and then report if I experience any changes

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar problem. I noticed that it works after waiting for a about 10 secs or else by locking the screen again and reentering password. I know there exists a better method but this works for me.

Comment: oh, interesting, so your approach is: *(1)* log in, touchpad is not working *(2)* lock screen  *(3)* wait for 10 sec *(4)* log in, touchpad is now working.

I will try that the next time and report!

Answer (score 0):

After long scouring forums and blogs, i've finally came to a solution, at least on my Asus box laptop.

With your favorite editor (vim, nano, etc.)
open the grub file:
`sudo vim /etc/default/grub`

Add `psmouse.proto=bare` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` as

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="psmouse.proto=bare quiet splash"`
then reflect these changes:

`sudo update-grub`

and finally reboot.

Found [here](https://medium.com/@OrkoHunter/touchpad-problem-with-asus-laptop-on-linux-9bfbaeee1ae6)

Other relevant refs that I hope will help other desperate souls in their search:

- [Similar issue/solution, other touchpads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041820/touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- Some explanations on why we sometimes need to pass parameters to the kernel, [to make mouse/keyboards work.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/what-does-the-i8042-nomux-1-kernel-option-do-during-booting-of-ubuntu)
- General ubuntu wiki guide on [debugging touchpad problems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection)
- [Kernel update solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux)